# Vue warn: 'Unknown custom element' with re-exported component

Tags: vue.js, components, es6-modules

I have an `index.js` file in my Vue project's `components` folder which allows me to import components like this:

```
import { home, search, tour } from '@/components';
```

The `index.js` file:

```
export { default as home } from './home/home.vue';
export { default as search } from './search/search.vue';
export { default as tour } from './tour/tour.vue';
export { default as tourItem } from './tour-item/tour-item.vue';
```

Now, when doing this with nested components (a component that should be used in another) it gives me the `unknown custom element` error.

I don't get why that error is thrown - it's just another component, right?

To be more clear, this works:

```
import tourItem from '@/components/tour-item/tour-item.vue';
```

And this doesn't:

```
import { tourItem } from '@/components';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try export children/local component just BEFORE parent in index.js. This solve problem in my case.

[Solution in Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/did-you-register-the-component-correctly-for-recursive-components-make-sure-to-provide-the-name/18292)